# Spinner — как установить значение по умолчанию при динамическом наполнении?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Хочется установить значение по умолчанию. Чтобы, допустим, в первом `Spinner` был доллар США, а во втором — Российский рубль. Прошу прощения за качество кода — сейчас интересует сам механизм.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Map<String, Currency> currencies;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        currencies = Converter.currencies;
        for (String s : currencies.keySet()) Log.d("currency", s);

        String[] currenciesArray = new String[currencies.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Currency s : currencies.values()) currenciesArray[i++] = String.format("%s (%s)", s.getCode(), geCurrencyName(s));

        Spinner spinnerFrom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerFrom);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, currenciesArray);
        arrayAdapterFrom.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerFrom.setAdapter(arrayAdapterFrom);

        Spinner spinnerTo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTo);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, currenciesArray);
        arrayAdapterTo.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerTo.setAdapter(arrayAdapterTo);
    }

    private String geCurrencyName(Currency s) {
        switch (s.getCode()) {
            case "AUD" : return "Австралийский доллар";
            case "AZN" : return "Азербайджанский манат";
            case "AMD" : return "Армянский драм";
            case "BYN" : return "Белорусский рубль";
            case "BGN" : return "Болгарский лев";
            case "BRL" : return "Бразильский реал";
            case "HUF" : return "Венгерский форинт";
            case "KRW" : return "Южнокорейский вон";
            case "HKD" : return "Гонгконгский доллар";
            case "DKK" : return "Датская крона";
            case "USD" : return "Доллар США";
            case "EUR" : return "Евро";
            case "INR" : return "Индийская рупия";
            case "KZT" : return "Казахский тенге";
            case "CAD" : return "Канадский доллар";
            case "KGS" : return "Киргизский сом";
            case "CNY" : return "Китайский юань";
            case "MDL" : return "Молдавский лей";
            case "TMT" : return "Туркменский манат";
            case "NOK" : return "Норвежская крона";
            case "PLN" : return "Польский злотый";
            case "RON" : return "Румынский лей";
            case "XDR" : return "СДР";
            case "SGD" : return "Сингапурский доллар";
            case "TJS" : return "Таджикский сомони";
            case "TRY" : return "Турецкая лира";
            case "UZS" : return "Узбекский сум";
            case "UAH" : return "Украинская гривна";
            case "GBP" : return "Фунт Стерлингов";
            case "CZK" : return "Чешская крона";
            case "SEK" : return "Шведская крона";
            case "CHF" : return "Швейцарский франк";
            case "ZAR" : return "Южноафриканский рэнд";
            case "JPY" : return "Японская йена";
            case "RUR" : return "Российский рубль";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Э-э-э... `spinner.setSelection(0);`?

Comment: Да, так и есть, спасибо!

Comment: RUR - это советский рубль, RUB - российский рубль, в частности,  разница в том, что для второго из класса `Currency` можно получить его символ " ₽ " (`Сurrency.getSymbol()`), кроме того, в  классе `Currency` есть замечательный метод `getDisplayName()`, который выводит полное имя валюты согласно стандарта, причем на языке текущей локали, например, для рубля: `Currency currency = Currency.getInstance("RUB"); String fullName = currency.getDisplayName();`

Comment: @pavlofff ты как всегда умничка :)

Comment: Спасибо! С моим `Currency` это не прокатит, потому что это не класс `java.util`, а специально написанный для приложения класс. Буду знать, что такой есть :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо @ЮрийСПБ за правильный ответ. Действительно, чтобы обозначить позицию по умолчанию при динамическом наполнении `Spinner`, достаточно применить `.setSelection(index)` после `.setAdapter(adapter);`

Не могу отметить комментарий как правильный, поэтому написал отдельный пост.